# What does this error in an equation mean !missing} inserted

Tags: errors

```
\\ $=\frac { { b }^{ 4 } }{ { n }^{ 4 } } \left.( \frac { { n }^{ 2 }+2n+1 }{ 4 }  \right.) =\frac { { b }^{ 4 } }{ 4 } \left.( \frac { { n }^{ 2 }+2n+1 }{ 4 }  \right.)  }  }  }
```

I have a problem with this part of the code, the following error appears

```
!Missing} inserted. <insterted text>}\\$
```

Comment: You enter math mode with `$`: do you ever leave math mode with a closing `$`?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please consider making the title of your question specific to the question, and providing a complete sample document that we can compile.

Comment: What should `\left.` and `\right.` do? They do nothing good and much bad.

Comment: This seems to be fragment of your code from question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290784/i-dont-know-how-to-fix-my-errors, where in my answer I provide complete working code. I also in my comment point where is error and what were other errors ...

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\frac { { b }^{ 4 } }{ { n }^{ 4 } } \left( \frac { { n }^{ 2 }+2n+1 }{ 4 }  \right) =\frac { { b }^{ 4 } }{ 4 } \left( \frac { { n }^{ 2 }+2n+1 }{ 4 }  \right)$
\end{document}
```

Note that I have written  `\left` and not `\left.` In your code there were to many curly brackets and `$` was missing.

[image]