# i dont know how to fix my errors

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\author{Jose de Jesus Montes Cruz}
\title{Tarea 1}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\part*{}
Instrucciones: Resuelve los siguientes problemas. Justifica bien tus respuestas.
\section*{}
1.- Demuestra que $\int _{ a }^{ 0 }{ x\quad dx=-\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ 2 }  }  $, para todo $a<0$
\\
\\Sea Pn=$\left\{ { t }_{ 0 }=a,{ t }_{ i },...,{ t }_{ n }=0 \right\}$ una particion uniforme de $ \left[ a,0 \right]$ 
\\
\\Sabemos:
\\${ t }_{ i }=a+1\left( \frac { -a }{ n }  \right) $
\\${ t }_{ i }-1=a+1\left( i-1 \right) \left( \frac { -a }{ n }  \right) $
\\${ t }_{ i }-\left( { t }_{ i }-1 \right) =\frac { -a }{ n }$ 
\\
\\Como f es decreciente:
\\$f\left( x \right) =x,\quad x\epsilon \left[ a,0 \right] $
\\$mi=f\left( { t }_{ i }-1 \right) ={ t }_{ i }-1=a+\left( i-1 \right) \left( \frac { -a }{ n }  \right) =a-\frac { \left( i-1 \right) \left( a \right)  }{ n } $
\\$Mi=f\left( { t }_{ i } \right) ={ t }_{ i }=a+1\left( \frac { -a }{ n }  \right) =a-\frac { i\left( a \right)  }{ n }=-\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ n } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ 1+\frac { -{ a }^{ 2 } }{ n }  } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ \frac { i-1 }{ n }  } $
\\
\\Por lo tanto:
\\
\\$L\left( f,Pn \right)$
\\
\\$ =\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ mi({ t }_{ i }- } { t }_{ i }-1)=\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ a-\frac { \left( i-1 \right) \left( a \right)  }{ n }  } \left[ -\frac { a }{ n }  \right] =\left( -\frac { a }{ n }  \right) \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ a-\left( \frac { \left( i-1 \right) \left( a \right)  }{ n }  \right)  }$
\\
\\$ =-\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ n } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ 1-\frac { \left( i-1 \right)  }{ n }  }=-\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ n } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ 1+\frac { -{ a }^{ 2 } }{ n }  } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ \frac { i-1 }{ n }  } =-\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ n } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ 1+\frac { -{ a }^{ 2 } }{ n }  } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n-1 }{ i }  $
\\
\\$=-\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ n } \bullet n+\frac { -{ a }^{ 2 } }{ n } \left[ \frac { n-1\left( \left( n-1 \right) +1 \right)  }{ 2 }  \right] =-{ a }^{ 2 }+\left( -\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ { n }^{ 2 } }  \right) \bullet \frac { \left( n-1 \right) \left( n \right)  }{ 2 } =-{ a }^{ 2 }+\frac { \left( { -a }^{ 2 } \right) \left( n-1 \right)  }{ 2n } $
\\
\\$=-{ a }^{ 2 }+\left( 1-\frac { n-1 }{ 2n }  \right) =-\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } \left( \frac { n-1 }{ { n }^{ 2 } }  \right) $
\\
\\$U\left( f,Pn \right)$
\\
\\$=\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ Mi\left[ { t }_{ i }-{ t }_{ i }-1 \right]  } =\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ a-\frac { ia }{ n }  } \left[ -\frac { a }{ n }  \right] =\frac { -a }{ n } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ a-\frac { ia }{ n }  } $
\\
\\$=-\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ n } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ 1-\frac { i }{ n }  } =-\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ n } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ 1+\left( -\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ n }  \right)  } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ \frac { i }{ n }  } =-{ a }^{ 2 }+\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ { n }^{ 2 } } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ i } $
\\
\\$=-{ a }^{ 2 }+\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ { n }^{ 2 } } \left( \frac { n\left( n+1 \right)  }{ 2 }  \right) =-\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } \left( \frac { n+1 }{ { n }^{ 2 } }  \right) $
\\
\\ Como limite superior y  inferior son iguales $\therefore \int _{ a }^{ 0 }{ xdx } =-\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } $ 
\section*{}
2.- Demuestra que $\int _{ a }^{ 0 }{ { x }^{ 2 }\quad dx=-\frac { { a }^{ 3 } }{ 3 }  } $, para todo $a<0$
\\
\\Sea Pn=$\left\{ { t }_{ 0 }=a,{ t }_{ i },...,{ t }_{ n }=0 \right\}$ una particion uniforme de $ \left[ a,0 \right]$ 
\\
\\Sabemos:
\\
\\$Mi={ t }_{ i }=a\left( a+\frac { -i }{ n }  \right) $
\\$mi={ t }_{ i }-{ t }_{ i }-1=\left( \frac { -a }{ n }  \right) $
\\
\\Por lo tanto:
\\
\\$L\left( f,Pn \right)$
\\
\\$=\sum _{ i=0 }^{ n-1 }{ mi } \left( { t }_{ 1 }-{ t }_{ 1 }-1 \right) =\sum _{ i=0 }^{ n-1 }{ mi\left( \frac { -a }{ n }  \right)  } =\frac { -a }{ n } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n-1 }{ { \left( { t }_{ i } \right)  }^{ 2 } } =\frac { -a }{ n } \sum _{ i=0 }^{ n-1 }{ \left( a\left( a+\frac { i }{ n }  \right)  \right)  } $
\\
\\$=-\frac { a }{ n } \bullet { a }^{ 2 }\sum _{ i=0 }^{ n-1 }{ { \left( \frac { 1-i }{ n }  \right)  }^{ 2 }=-\frac { { a }^{ 3 } }{ { n }^{ 3 } }  } \sum _{ i=0 }^{ n-1 }{ { i }^{ 2 } } =\quad -\frac { { a }^{ 3 } }{ { n }^{ 3 } } \bullet \left( \frac { n+1(2n+1) }{ { 2n }^{ 2 } }  \right) $
\\
\\$U\left( f,Pn \right)$
\\
\\$=\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ Mi\left( { t }_{ 1 }-{ t }_{ 1 }-1 \right) =\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ \left( -\frac { a }{ n }  \right) =-\frac { a }{ n } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ { \left( { t }_{ 1 } \right)  }^{ 2 } } =-\frac { a }{ n } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ { a }^{ 2 }\left( \frac { 1+i }{ n }  \right) ^{ 2 } }  }  } $
\\
\\$=-\frac { { a }^{ 3 } }{ n } \sum _{ i=0 }^{ n-1 }{ { \left( \frac { n-1 }{ 0 } n \right)  }^{ 2 } } =-\frac { { a }^{ 3 } }{ n^{ 3 } } \sum _{ i=0 }^{ n-1 }{ { i }^{ 2 } } =-\frac { { a }^{ 3 } }{ 3 } \bullet \left( \frac { n+1\left( 2n+1 \right)  }{ 2n^{ 2 } }  \right) $
\\
\\ 
\\Como limite superior e inferior son iguales $\therefore \int _{ a }^{ 0 }{ { x }^{ 2 }\quad dx=-\frac { { a }^{ 3 } }{ 3 }  } $ 
\\
\\
\section*{}
3.- Demuestra que $\int _{ 0 }^{ b }{ { x }^{ 3 } } \quad dx=\frac { { b }^{ 4 } }{ 4 } $, para todo $a<0$
\\
\\Sea:
\\ $\left[ 0,b \right]$
\\ $Pn=\left[ t0=a,{ t }_{ 1 }, { t }_{ 2 }...{ t }_{ n }=b \right]$
\\
\\Sabemos:
\\
\\ $ti=\left( \frac { -ib }{ n }  \right)$
\\ $ti-1=\frac { \left( i-1 \right) b }{ n }$
\\ $Mi=ti={ \left( ti \right)  }^{ 3 }\\ mi=ti-{ ti }_{ -1 }=\left( \frac { -a }{ n }  \right)$ 
\\
\\
\\Por lo tanto: 
\\
\\
\\ $U\left.( f,Pn \right.) =\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ Mi\left.( \frac { b }{ n }  \right.) =\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ \left.( \frac { b }{ n }  \right.) \left.( \frac { ib }{ n }  \right.) ^{ 3 }=\frac { b }{ n } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ \left( \frac { ib }{ n }  \right.) ^{ 3 }=\frac { { b }^{ 4 } }{ { n }^{ 4 } } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ \left.( i \right.) ^{ 3 } }
\\
\\ $:=\frac {{ { b }^{ 4 } }{ { n }^{ 4 } } \left.( \frac { { n }^{ 2 }+2n+1 }{ 4 }  \right.) =\frac { { b }^{ 4 } }{ 4 } \left.( \frac { { n }^{ 2 }+2n+1 }{ 4 }  \right.)}$
\\
\\
\\ $L\left.( f,Pn \right.) =\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ mi\left.( \frac { b }{ n }  \right.) = } \sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ \left.( \frac { b }{ n }  \right.) \left.( \frac { \left.( i-1 \right.) b }{ n }  \right.) ^{ 3 }$
\\
\\$=\sum _{ i=0 }^{ n-1 }{ { i }^{ 3 } } =\frac { { b }^{ 4 } }{ 4 } \left.( \frac { { n }^{ 2 }+2n+1 }{ 4 }  \right.)  }$
\\
\\
\\Como limite superior e inferior son iguales $\therefore \int _{ 0 }^{ b }{ { x }^{ 3 }dx } =\frac { { b }^{ 4 } }{ 4 } $
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\section*{}
4.- Considera las funciones ${ f }_{ 1 }\left( x \right) =1+{ x }^{ 2 }$, ${ f }_{ 2 }\left( x \right) =\sqrt { x }$, ${ f }_{ 3 }\left( x \right) ={ x }^{ 2 }-\frac { x }{ 2 } $y ${ f }_{ 4 }\left( x \right) =\ln { \left( 1+x \right)  }$ para $x \epsilon \left[ 0,1 \right]$. Calcula las sumas superiores e inferiores utilizando particiones superiores con $n \epsilon \left\{ 10,15,25 \right\} $. 
\\
\\Para la funcion ${ f }_{ 1 }\left( x \right) =1+{ x }^{ 2 }$
\\Con n = 10
\\
\\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (1+1.01+1.04+1.09+1.16+1.25+1.36+1.49+1.64+1.81)=1.285$
\\
\\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
paticion & ax & f(ax) \\ 
\hline 
(0,1/10) & 1/10 & 1 \\ 
\hline 
(1/10,2/10) & 1/10 & 1.01 \\ 
\hline 
(2/10,3/10) & 1/10 & 1.04 \\ 
\hline 
(3/10,4/10) & 1/10 & 1.09 \\ 
\hline 
(4/10,5/10) & 1/10 & 1.16 \\ 
\hline 
(5/10,6/10) & 1/10 & 1.25 \\ 
\hline 
(6/10,7/10) & 1/10 & 1.36 \\ 
\hline 
(7/10,8/10) & 1/10 & 1.49 \\ 
\hline 
(8/10,9/10) & 1/10 & 1.64 \\ 
\hline 
(9/10,1) & 1/10 & 1.81 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\\
\\
\\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (1.01+1.04+1.09+1.16+1.25+1.36+1.49+1.64+1.81+2)=1.385$
\\
\\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
paticion & ax & f(ax) \\ 
\hline 
(0,1/10) & 1/10 & 1.01 \\ 
\hline 
(1/10,2/10) & 1/10 & 1.04 \\ 
\hline 
(2/10,3/10) & 1/10 & 1.09 \\ 
\hline 
(3/10,4/10) & 1/10 & 1.16 \\ 
\hline 
(4/10,5/10) & 1/10 & 1.25 \\ 
\hline 
(5/10,6/10) & 1/10 & 1.36 \\ 
\hline 
(6/10,7/10) & 1/10 & 1.49 \\ 
\hline 
(7/10,8/10) & 1/10 & 1.64 \\ 
\hline 
(8/10,9/10) & 1/10 & 1.81 \\ 
\hline 
(9/10,1) & 1/10 & 2 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\Con n=15
\\
\\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (1+1.04+1.017+1.04+1.071+1.111+1.16+1.217+1.284+1.36+1.444+1.537+1.64+1.75+1.87)=1.300$
\\
\\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
particion & n & f(x) \\ 
\hline 
(0,1/15) & 1/15 & 1 \\ 
\hline 
(1/15,2/15) & 1/15 & 1.004 \\ 
\hline 
(2/15,3/15) & 1/15 & 1.017 \\ 
\hline 
(3/15,4/15) & 1/15 & 1.04 \\ 
\hline 
(4/15,5/15) & 1/15 & 1.071 \\ 
\hline 
(5/15,6/15) & 1/15 & 1.111 \\ 
\hline 
(6/15,7/15) & 1/15 & 1.16 \\ 
\hline 
(7/15,8/15) & 1/15 & 1.217 \\ 
\hline 
(8/15,9/15) & 1/15 & 1.284 \\ 
\hline 
(9/15,10/15) & 1/15 & 1.36 \\ 
\hline 
(10/15,11/15) & 1/15 & 1.444 \\ 
\hline 
(11/15,12/15) & 1/15 & 1.537 \\ 
\hline 
(12/15,13/15) & 1/15 & 1.64 \\ 
\hline 
(13/15,14/15) & 1/15 & 1.75 \\ 
\hline 
(14/15,1) & 1/15 & 1.87 \\ 
\hline 

\end{tabular} 
\\
\\
\\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (1.04+1.017+1.04+1.071+1.111+1.16+1.217+1.284+1.36+1.444+1.537+1.64+1.75+1.87+2)=1.367$
\\
\\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
particion & n & f(x) \\ 
\hline 
(0,1/15) & 1/15 & 1.004 \\ 
\hline 
(1/15,2/15) & 1/15 & 1.017 \\ 
\hline 
(2/15,3/15) & 1/15 & 1.04 \\ 
\hline 
(3/15,4/15) & 1/15 & 1.071 \\ 
\hline 
(4/15,5/15) & 1/15 & 1.111 \\ 
\hline 
(5/15,6/15) & 1/15 & 1.16 \\ 
\hline 
(6/15,7/15) & 1/15 & 1.217 \\ 
\hline 
(7/15,8/15) & 1/15 & 1.284 \\ 
\hline 
(8/15,9/15) & 1/15 & 1.36 \\ 
\hline 
(9/15,10/15) & 1/15 & 1.444 \\ 
\hline 
(10/15,11/15) & 1/15 & 1.537 \\ 
\hline 
(11/15,12/15) & 1/15 & 1.64 \\ 
\hline 
(12/15,13/15) & 1/15 & 1.75 \\ 
\hline 
(13/15,14/15) & 1/15 & 1.87 \\ 
\hline 
(14/15,1) & 1/15 & 2 \\ 
\hline 

\end{tabular} 
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\ con n=25
\\
\\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (1+1.001+1.006+1.014+1.025+1.04+1.057+1.078+1.102+1.129+1.16+1.193+1.230+1.270+1.313+1.36+1.409+1.462+1.518+1.577+1.64+
1.705+1.774+1.846+1.921=1.313$
\\
\\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
particion & n & f(x) \\ 
\hline 
(0,1/25) & 1/25 & 1 \\ 
\hline 
(1/25,2/25) & 1/25 & 1.001 \\ 
\hline 
(2/25,3/25) & 1/25 & 1.006 \\ 
\hline 
(3/25,4/25) & 1/25 & 1.014 \\ 
\hline 
(4/25,5/25) & 1/25 & 1.025 \\ 
\hline 
(5/25,6/25) & 1/25 & 1.04 \\ 
\hline 
(6/25,7/25) & 1/25 & 1.057 \\ 
\hline 
(7/25,8/25) & 1/25 & 1.078 \\ 
\hline 
(8/25,9/25) & 1/25 & 1.102 \\ 
\hline 
(9/25,10/25) & 1/25 & 1.129 \\ 
\hline 
(10/25,11/25) & 1/25 & 1.16 \\ 
\hline 
(11/25,12/25) & 1/25 & 1.193 \\ 
\hline 
(12/25,13/25) & 1/25 & 1.230 \\ 
\hline 
(13/25,14/25) & 1/25 & 1.270 \\ 
\hline 
(14/25,15/25) & 1/25 & 1.313 \\ 
\hline 
(15/25,16/25) & 1/25 & 1.36 \\ 
\hline 
(16/25,17/25) & 1/25 & 1.409 \\ 
\hline 
(17/25,18/25) & 1/25 & 1.462 \\ 
\hline 
(18/25,19/25) & 1/25 & 1.518 \\ 
\hline 
(19/25,20/25) & 1/25 & 1.577 \\ 
\hline 
(20/25,21/25) & 1/25 & 1.64 \\ 
\hline 
(21/25,22/25) & 1/25 & 1.705 \\ 
\hline 
(22/25,23/25) & 1/25 & 1.774 \\ 
\hline 
(23/25,24/25) & 1/25 & 1.846 \\ 
\hline 
(24/25,1) & 1/25 & 1.921 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (1.001+1.006+1.014+1.025+1.04+1.057+1.078+1.102+1.129+1.16+1.193+1.230+1.270+1.313+1.36+1.409+1.462+1.518+1.577+1.64+
1.705+1.774+1.846+1.921+2=1.353$
\\
\\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
particion & n & f(x) \\ 
\hline 
(0,1/25) & 1/25 & 1 \\ 
\hline 
(1/25,2/25) & 1/25 & 1.001 \\ 
\hline 
(2/25,3/25) & 1/25 & 1.006 \\ 
\hline 
(3/25,4/25) & 1/25 & 1.014 \\ 
\hline 
(4/25,5/25) & 1/25 & 1.025 \\ 
\hline 
(5/25,6/25) & 1/25 & 1.04 \\ 
\hline 
(6/25,7/25) & 1/25 & 1.057 \\ 
\hline 
(7/25,8/25) & 1/25 & 1.078 \\ 
\hline 
(8/25,9/25) & 1/25 & 1.102 \\ 
\hline 
(9/25,10/25) & 1/25 & 1.129 \\ 
\hline 
(10/25,11/25) & 1/25 & 1.16 \\ 
\hline 
(11/25,12/25) & 1/25 & 1.193 \\ 
\hline 
(12/25,13/25) & 1/25 & 1.230 \\ 
\hline 
(13/25,14/25) & 1/25 & 1.270 \\ 
\hline 
(14/25,15/25) & 1/25 & 1.313 \\ 
\hline 
(15/25,16/25) & 1/25 & 1.36 \\ 
\hline 
(16/25,17/25) & 1/25 & 1.409 \\ 
\hline 
(17/25,18/25) & 1/25 & 1.462 \\ 
\hline 
(18/25,19/25) & 1/25 & 1.518 \\ 
\hline 
(19/25,20/25) & 1/25 & 1.577 \\ 
\hline 
(20/25,21/25) & 1/25 & 1.64 \\ 
\hline 
(21/25,22/25) & 1/25 & 1.705 \\ 
\hline 
(22/25,23/25) & 1/25 & 1.774 \\ 
\hline 
(23/25,24/25) & 1/25 & 1.846 \\ 
\hline 
(24/25,1) & 1/25 & 1.921 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\Para la funcion: ${ f }_{ 2 }\left( x \right) =\sqrt { x }$
\\Con n=10
\\
\\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (0+.316+.447+.547+.632+.707+.774+.836+.894+.948)=.610$
\\
\\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
paticion & ax & f(ax) \\ 
\hline 
(0,1/10) & 1/10 & 0 \\ 
\hline 
(1/10,2/10) & 1/10 & .316 \\ 
\hline 
(2/10,3/10) & 1/10 & .447 \\ 
\hline 
(3/10,4/10) & 1/10 & .547 \\ 
\hline 
(4/10,5/10) & 1/10 & .632 \\ 
\hline 
(5/10,6/10) & 1/10 & .707 \\ 
\hline 
(6/10,7/10) & 1/10 & .774 \\ 
\hline 
(7/10,8/10) & 1/10 & .836 \\ 
\hline 
(8/10,9/10) & 1/10 & .894 \\ 
\hline 
(9/10,1) & 1/10 & .948 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\\
\\
\\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (.316+.447+.547+.632+.707+.774+.836+.894+.948+1)=.710$
\\
\\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
paticion & ax & f(ax) \\ 
\hline 
(0,1/10) & 1/10 & .316 \\ 
\hline 
(1/10,2/10) & 1/10 & .447 \\ 
\hline 
(2/10,3/10) & 1/10 & .547 \\ 
\hline 
(3/10,4/10) & 1/10 & .632 \\ 
\hline 
(4/10,5/10) & 1/10 & .707 \\ 
\hline 
(5/10,6/10) & 1/10 & .774 \\ 
\hline 
(6/10,7/10) & 1/10 & .836 \\ 
\hline 
(7/10,8/10) & 1/10 & .894 \\ 
\hline 
(8/10,9/10) & 1/10 & .948 \\ 
\hline 
(9/10,1) & 1/10 & 1 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\Con n=15
\\
\\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (0+.258+.365+.447+.516+.577+.632+.683+.730+.774+.816+.856+.894+.930+.966)=.629$
\\
\\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
particion & n & f(x) \\ 
\hline 
(0,1/15) & 1/15 & 0 \\ 
\hline 
(1/15,2/15) & 1/15 & .258 \\ 
\hline 
(2/15,3/15) & 1/15 & .365 \\ 
\hline 
(3/15,4/15) & 1/15 & .447 \\ 
\hline 
(4/15,5/15) & 1/15 & .516 \\ 
\hline 
(5/15,6/15) & 1/15 & .577 \\ 
\hline 
(6/15,7/15) & 1/15 & .632 \\ 
\hline 
(7/15,8/15) & 1/15 & .683 \\ 
\hline 
(8/15,9/15) & 1/15 & .730 \\ 
\hline 
(9/15,10/15) & 1/15 & .774 \\ 
\hline 
(10/15,11/15) & 1/15 & .816 \\ 
\hline 
(11/15,12/15) & 1/15 & .856 \\ 
\hline 
(12/15,13/15) & 1/15 & .894 \\ 
\hline 
(13/15,14/15) & 1/15 & .930 \\ 
\hline 
(14/15,1) & 1/15 & .966 \\ 
\hline 

\end{tabular} 
\\
\\
\\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (.258+.365+.447+.516+.577+.632+.683+.730+.774+.816+.856+.894+.930+.966+1)=.696$
\\
\\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
particion & n & f(x) \\ 
\hline 
(0,1/15) & 1/15 & .258 \\ 
\hline 
(1/15,2/15) & 1/15 & .365 \\ 
\hline 
(2/15,3/15) & 1/15 & .447 \\ 
\hline 
(3/15,4/15) & 1/15 & .516 \\ 
\hline 
(4/15,5/15) & 1/15 & .577 \\ 
\hline 
(5/15,6/15) & 1/15 & .632 \\ 
\hline 
(6/15,7/15) & 1/15 & .683 \\ 
\hline 
(7/15,8/15) & 1/15 & .730 \\ 
\hline 
(8/15,9/15) & 1/15 & .774 \\ 
\hline 
(9/15,10/15) & 1/15 & .816 \\ 
\hline 
(10/15,11/15) & 1/15 & .856 \\ 
\hline 
(11/15,12/15) & 1/15 & .894 \\ 
\hline 
(12/15,13/15) & 1/15 & .930 \\ 
\hline 
(13/15,14/15) & 1/15 & .966 \\ 
\hline 
(14/15,1) & 1/15 & 1 \\ 
\hline 

\end{tabular} 
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\ con n=25
\\
\\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (0+.2+.282+.364+.4+.447+.489+.529+.565+.6+.632+.663+.692+.721+.748+.774+.8+.824+.848+.871+.894+.916+.938+.959+.979)=.645$
\\
\\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
particion & n & f(x) \\ 
\hline 
(0,1/25) & 1/25 & 0 \\ 
\hline 
(1/25,2/25) & 1/25 & .2 \\ 
\hline 
(2/25,3/25) & 1/25 & .282 \\ 
\hline 
(3/25,4/25) & 1/25 & .364 \\ 
\hline 
(4/25,5/25) & 1/25 & .4 \\ 
\hline 
(5/25,6/25) & 1/25 & .447 \\ 
\hline 
(6/25,7/25) & 1/25 & .489 \\ 
\hline 
(7/25,8/25) & 1/25 & .529 \\ 
\hline 
(8/25,9/25) & 1/25 & .565 \\ 
\hline 
(9/25,10/25) & 1/25 & .6 \\ 
\hline 
(10/25,11/25) & 1/25 & .632 \\ 
\hline 
(11/25,12/25) & 1/25 & .663 \\ 
\hline 
(12/25,13/25) & 1/25 & .692 \\ 
\hline 
(13/25,14/25) & 1/25 & .721 \\ 
\hline 
(14/25,15/25) & 1/25 & .748 \\ 
\hline 
(15/25,16/25) & 1/25 & .774 \\ 
\hline 
(16/25,17/25) & 1/25 & .8 \\ 
\hline 
(17/25,18/25) & 1/25 & .824 \\ 
\hline 
(18/25,19/25) & 1/25 & .848 \\ 
\hline 
(19/25,20/25) & 1/25 & .871 \\ 
\hline 
(20/25,21/25) & 1/25 & .894 \\ 
\hline 
(21/25,22/25) & 1/25 & .916 \\ 
\hline 
(22/25,23/25) & 1/25 & .938 \\ 
\hline 
(23/25,24/25) & 1/25 & .959 \\ 
\hline 
(24/25,1) & 1/25 & .979 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (.2+.282+.364+.4+.447+.489+.529+.565+.6+.632+.663+.692+.721+.748+.774+.8+.824+.848+.871+.894+.916+.938+.959+.979+1)=.685$
\\
\\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
particion & n & f(x) \\ 
\hline 
(0,1/25) & 1/25 & .2 \\ 
\hline 
(1/25,2/25) & 1/25 & .282 \\ 
\hline 
(2/25,3/25) & 1/25 & .364 \\ 
\hline 
(3/25,4/25) & 1/25 & .4 \\ 
\hline 
(4/25,5/25) & 1/25 & .447 \\ 
\hline 
(5/25,6/25) & 1/25 & .489 \\ 
\hline 
(6/25,7/25) & 1/25 & .529 \\ 
\hline 
(7/25,8/25) & 1/25 & .565 \\ 
\hline 
(8/25,9/25) & 1/25 & .6 \\ 
\hline 
(9/25,10/25) & 1/25 & .632 \\ 
\hline 
(10/25,11/25) & 1/25 & .663 \\ 
\hline 
(11/25,12/25) & 1/25 & .692 \\ 
\hline 
(12/25,13/25) & 1/25 & .721 \\ 
\hline 
(13/25,14/25) & 1/25 & .748 \\ 
\hline 
(14/25,15/25) & 1/25 & .774 \\ 
\hline 
(15/25,16/25) & 1/25 & .8 \\ 
\hline 
(16/25,17/25) & 1/25 & .824 \\ 
\hline 
(17/25,18/25) & 1/25 & .848 \\ 
\hline 
(18/25,19/25) & 1/25 & .871 \\ 
\hline 
(19/25,20/25) & 1/25 & .894 \\ 
\hline 
(20/25,21/25) & 1/25 & .916 \\ 
\hline 
(21/25,22/25) & 1/25 & .938 \\ 
\hline 
(22/25,23/25) & 1/25 & .959 \\ 
\hline 
(23/25,24/25) & 1/25 & .979 \\ 
\hline 
(24/25,1) & 1/25 & 1 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\\
\\
\\Para la funcion: ${ f }_{ 3 }\left( x \right) ={ x }^{ 2 }-\frac { x }{ 2 } $
\\Con n=10
\\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (0-.04-.06-.06-.04+0+.06+.14+.24+.36)=.059$
\\
\\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (-.04-.06-.06-.04+0+.06+.14+.24+.36+.5)=.11$
\\
\\Con n=15
\\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (0-.02-.04-.06-.062-.055-.04-.015+.017+.06-.11+.17+.24+.31+.40)=.053$
\\
\\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (-.02-.04-.06-.062-.055-.04-.015+.017+.06-.11+.17+.24+.31+.40+.5)=.086$
\\
\\Con n=25
\\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (0-.018-.033-.045-.054-.06-.062-.061-.057-.05-.04-.026-.009+.010+.033+.06+.089+.122+.158+.197+.24+.28+.33+.38+.44)=.073$
\\
\\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (-.018-.033-.045-.054-.06-.062-.061-.057-.05-.04-.026-.009+.010+.033+.06+.089+.122+.158+.197+.24+.28+.33+.38+.44+.5)=.093$
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\Para la funcion: ${ f }_{ 4 }\left( x \right) =\ln { \left( 1+x \right)  }$
\\Con n=10
\\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (0+.099+.18+.26+.33+.40+.47+.53+.58+.64)=.349$
\\
\\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (.099+.18+.26+.33+.40+.47+.53+.58+.64+.69)=.418$
\\
\\Con n=15
\\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (0+.06+.12+.18+.23+.28+.33+.38+.42+.47+.51+.55+.58+.62+.65)=.359$
\\
\\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (.06+.12+.18+.23+.28+.33+.38+.42+.47+.51+.55+.58+.62+.65+.69)=.405$
\\
\\Con n=25
\\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (0+.03+.07+.11+.14+.18+.21+.24+.27+.30+.33+.36+.39+.41+.44+.47+.49+.51+.54+.56+.58+.60+.63+.65+.67)=.367$
\\
\\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (.03+.07+.11+.14+.18+.21+.24+.27+.30+.33+.36+.39+.41+.44+.47+.49+.51+.54+.56+.58+.60+.63+.65+.67+.69)=.395$
\\
\\
\section*{}
5.- Dibuja las regiones representadas por las siguientes integrales, y luego, calcula el area de dichas regiones utilizando geometria elemental.
\\
\\$\left. a \right)$ $\int _{ -3 }^{ 3 }{ 2x dx } $
\\
\\\includegraphics[scale=.2]{../Desktop/Nueva carpeta (3)/graph1.png} 
\\sabemos que el area de un triangulo es $A=\frac { b\cdot h }{ 2 } $
\\Se puede observar la presencia de 2 triangulos que relacionan la f(x) en la region acotada
\\$A_{ 1 }=\frac { \left( 3-0 \right) \left( 6 \right)  }{ 2 } =9{ u }^{ 2 }$
\\$A_{ 2 }=\frac { \left( 0-3 \right) \left( 6 \right)  }{ 2 } =-9{ u }^{ 2 }$
\\$A_{ T }={ A }_{ 1 }+{ A }_{ 2 }=9{ u }^{ 2 }-9{ u }^{ 2 }=0$
\\
\\
\\$\left. b \right)$ $\int _{ -2 }^{ 3 }{ (2x+4)dx } $
\\
\\$A_{ T }=\frac { \left( 3-(-2) \right) \left( 10 \right)  }{ 2 } =25{ u }^{ 2 }$
\\
\\
\\
\\$\left. c \right)$ $\int _{ -2 }^{ 3 }{ 4 dx } $
\\
\\$A=(1-(-2))(4)=12{ u }^{ 2 }$
\\
\\
\\
\\$\left. d \right)$ $\int _{ 0 }^{ 5 }{ \sqrt { 25-{ x }^{ 2 } } dx } $
\\
\\$A=\frac { \pi { r }^{ 2 } }{ 4 } =\frac { \pi (5)^{ 2 } }{ 4 } =\frac { 25\pi  }{ 4 } =19.63{ u }^{ 2 }$
\\
\\
\\
\\$\left. e \right)$ $\int _{ -2 }^{ 3 }{ \left| x \right| dx } $
\\ 
\\$A_{ 1 }=\frac { \left( 3-0 \right) \left( 3 \right)  }{ 2 } =9/2{ u }^{ 2 }$
\\$A_{ 2 }=\frac { \left( 0-(-2) \right) \left( 2 \right)  }{ 2 } =2{ u }^{ 2 }$
\\$A_{ T }={ A }_{ 1 }+{ A }_{ 2 }=9/2{ u }^{ 2 }+2{ u }^{ 2 }=06.5{ u }^{ 2 }$
\\
\\
\\
\\$\left. f \right)$ $\int _{ -1 }^{ 1 }{ \left( 2x-\left| x \right|  \right) dx } $
\\
\\
\\$A_{ 1 }=\frac { \left( (1-0) \right) \left( 1 \right)  }{ 2 } =1/2{ u }^{ 2 }$
\\$A_{ 2 }=\frac { \left( 0-(-1) \right) \left( -3 \right)  }{ 2 } =-3/2{ u }^{ 2 }$
\\$A_{ T }={ A }_{ 1 }+{ A }_{ 2 }=1/2{ u }^{ 2 }-3/2{ u }^{ 2 }=-1{ u }^{ 2 }$ pero por valor absoluto es positivo.
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\section*{}
6.- Evalua las integrales para la funcion f que se muestra en la figura de abajo. 
\\
\\$\left. a \right)$ $\int _{ 0 }^{ 2 }{ f\left( x \right)dx }$ 
\\
\\el area del primer semicirculo sera negativa por estasdebajo del eje "x" y se debe divdir entre 2 ya que es un semicirculo
\\
\\${ A }=-\frac { \pi { r }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } =-\frac { \pi { \left( 1 \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } =-\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } $
\\
\\
\\
\\$\left. b \right)$ $\int _{ 0 }^{ 6 }{ f\left( x \right) dx }$
\\
\\Sabemos:
\\${ A_{ 1 } }=-\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } $
\\y
\\${ A_{ 2 } }=\frac { \pi { r }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } =\frac { \pi { \left( 2 \right)  }^{ 2 } }{ 2 } =\frac { 4\pi  }{ 2 } =2\pi $
\\Entonces el area total=
\\$ { A_{ T } }={ A }_{ 1 }+{ A }_{ 2 }=-\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } +2\pi =\frac { 3\pi  }{ 2 } $
\\
\\
\\
\\$\left. c \right)$ $\int _{ 1 }^{ 4 }{ f\left( x \right) dx }$
\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This is, wow, really difficult to do anything with, we need you to break things down a little bit into specific problems (with the full error message provided) and [minimal working examples](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?lq=1).

Comment: (1) LaTeX is not Word (and similar programs), so become more familiar how to wrote LaTeX document (2) errors start in line 100, where you have lost one `$` and have total mes of curly braces, (3) \you wrongly use `\left.(` and `\right.)`, (4) for further help you need to clean up your code from all necessary `\ \`, that (5) we can help you further.

Comment: this appears to be the same as this question: [I'm new on latex and i don't know what is the error](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290775/579)

Answer (score 2):

First thing first, When you use commands like `\section*{}` , you actually need to write something in it !!

```
1.- Demuestra que $\int _{ a }^{ 0 }{ x\quad dx=-\frac { { a }^{ 2 } }{ 2 }  }  $, para todo $a<0$ \\
```

Which I suppose from this line, it should be something like:

\section*{Demuestra}

Which honestly, doesn't make any sense.   :)

Are you trying to make an homework, or are you trying to create an assignment ?

It seems like your doing an homework, so maybe you should stick with something like this:

```
 \begin{document}
     \section*{Instructiones}
       Resuelve los siguientes problemas. Justifica bien tus respuestas.


     \begin{enumerate}[1)]
     \item % 1)
          .
          .
          .
     \item % 2)
          .
          .
          .

\end{enumerate}






\end{document}
```

Comment: This is minor part of all errors in document. See my comment above.

Comment: true that, but at least it's a beginning !

Comment: I agree with you, however, I expect that Yaj Yaj will edit his/her question and remove all necessary backslashes, than read my comment and correct mentioned equation, than we can help further. Your point about `\section{...}` is very essential!

Comment: Yah well, after reading a bit, I think you're point is even stronger. Simple stuff like `\frac{}{}` can<t even be read properly, not to mentionne the over abused  `{ { { }^{ } }{} } ` notation.

Answer (score 1):

Below is your code with corrected all your error (almost  2 hour of work ...). Also is for first two pages (till to item 3 is reformatted into form usual used in latex. For this purpose i replace `amsmath` with `mathtools`, which provide macro `\shortintertext`.

Your code has so many errors that give up in their counting. In formating of document I use answer of Sebastien Comtois. And let me repeat my comment:

- LaTeX is not Word (and similar programs), so become more familiar how to wrote LaTeX document
- errors start in line 100, where you have lost one $ and have total mes of curly braces,
- you wrongly use `\left.(` and `\right.)` (they not match),
- for further help you need to clean up your code from all necessary `\\`, that  we can help you further. How to do this, I show on beginning of your code.

[image]

Code:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    \usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
    \author{Jose de Jesus Montes Cruz}
    \title{Tarea 1}

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle

\section{Instrucciones} 
Resuelve los siguientes problemas. Justifica bien tus respuestas.

    \begin{enumerate}
\item   Demuestra que $\int _a^{ 0 }{ x\quad dx=-\frac {a^{2}}{2}  }  $, para todo $a<0$

Sea $Pn=\left\{t_{0} =a,t_{i},...,t_{n}=0\right\}$ una particion uniforme de $[a,0]$

Sabemos:
    \begin{align*}
t_{i}   & = a+1\left(\frac{-a}{n}\right)                    \\
t_{i}-1 & = a+1\left(i-1\right)\left(\frac{-a}{n} \right)   \\
t_{i}-(t_{i}-1) 
        & = \frac{-a}{n}
    \intertext{Como $f$ es decreciente:}
f(x)    & = x,\quad x\epsilon \left[ a,0 \right]        \\
mi      & = f(t_{i}-1) = t_{i}-1
          = a+(i-1)\left(\frac{-a}{n}\right) 
          = a-\frac{(i-1)(a)}{n}                        
    \shortintertext{and}
Mi      & = f(t_i)
          = t_{i}
          = a+1 \left(\frac{-a}{n}\right) 
          = a- \frac{i(a)}{n} 
          = -\frac{a^{2}}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} 1+\frac{-a^{2}}{n}
                            \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i-1}{n}
    \end{align*}
Por lo tanto:
    \begin{align*}
&   L(f,Pn)     \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n} mi(t_{i} - t_{i}-1)
  = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a-\frac{(i-1)(a)}{n}\left[-\frac{a}{n}\right] 
  = \left(-\frac{a}{n}\right) \sum_{i=1}^{n} a-\left(\frac{(i-1)(a)}{n}\right)  \\
& = -\frac{a^{2}}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1-\frac{(i-1)}{n}
  = -\frac{a^{2}}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1+\frac{-a^{2}}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i-1}{n}
  = -\frac{a^{2}}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1+\frac{-a^{2}}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i      \\
& = -\frac{a^{2}}{n} \bullet n+\frac{-a^{2}}{n}
        \left[\frac{n-1\left(\left(n-1\right)+1\right)}{2}\right]
  = -a^{2}+\left(-\frac{a^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)\bullet\frac{(n-1)(n)}{2}
  = -a^{2}+\frac{(-a ^{2})(n-1)}{2n}                                            \\
& = - a^{2}+\left(1-\frac{n-1}{2n}\right)                                       \\
& = - \frac{a^{2}}{2} \left(\frac{n-1}{n^{2}}\right)                            
    \intertext{and}
&   U(f,Pn)     \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{n} Mi\left[t_{i}-t_{i}-1 \right]
  = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a-\frac{ia}{n}\left[-\frac{a}{n}\right]
  = \frac{-a}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a-\frac{ia}{n}                                  \\
& = -\frac{a^{2}}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  1-\frac{i}{n}
  = -\frac{a^{2}}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  1+\left(-\frac{a^{2}}{n} \right)
            \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n}
  = -a^{2}+\frac{a^{2}} n^{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i}                                 \\
& = -a^{2}+\frac{a^{2}} n^{2}\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)
  = -\frac{a^{2}}{2} \left(\frac{n+1}{n^{2}}\right)
    \end{align*}
Como limite superior $y$ inferior son iguales 
    $\therefore \int_{a}^{0}x\,dx =-\frac{a^{2}}{2}$
%%%%
\item   Demuestra que $\int_{a}^{0}x^{2}\,dx=-\frac{a^{3}}{3}$, para todo $a<0$
    Sea Pn=$\{t_{0}=a,t_{i},...,t_{n}=0\}$ una particion uniforme de $[a,0]$.

    Sabemos:
    \begin{align*}
Mi & = t_{i}=a\left(a+\frac{-i}{n}\right)   
    \shortintertext{and}
mi & = t_{i}-t_{i}-1
     = \left(\frac{-a}{n}\right)
    \intertext{Por lo tanto:}
L(f,Pn)         \\
    & = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} mi (t_{1}-t_{1}-1)
      = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} mi\left(\frac{-a}{n}\right)
      = \frac{-a}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (t_{i})^{2}
      = \frac{-a}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(a\left(a+\frac{i}{n}\right)\right) \\
    & = -\frac{a}{n} \bullet a^{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1-i}{n}\right)^{2}
      = -\frac{a^{3}}{n^{3}} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} i^{2}
      = -\frac{a^{3}}{n^{3}} \bullet \left(\frac{n+1(2n+1)}{2n^{2}} \right)
    \end{align*}

Como limite superior e inferior son iguales 
    $\therefore \int_a^{0} x^{2}\, dx =-\frac{a^{3}}{3}$


%    \end{enumerate}
%    \end{document}

\item   Demuestra que $\int _{ 0 }^{ b }{ { x }^{ 3 } } \quad dx=\frac { { b }^{ 4 } }{ 4 } $, para todo $a<0$
    \\
    \\Sea:
    \\ $\left[ 0,b \right]$
    \\ $Pn=\left[ t0=a,t_{ 1 }, t_{2}...t_{n}=b \right]$
    \\
    \\Sabemos:
    \\
    \\ $ti=\left( \frac { -ib }{n}  \right)$
    \\ $ti-1=\frac { (i-1) b }{n}$
    \\ $Mi=ti={ \left( ti \right)  }^{ 3 }\\ mi=ti-{ ti }_{ -1 }=\left( \frac { -a }{n}  \right)$

Por lo tanto:

$U\left(f,Pn \right) = \sum _{i=1 }^{n} Mi\left(\frac{b}{n}\right) 
                     = \sum _{i=1 }^{n}   \left(\frac{b}{n}\right)
                            \left(\frac{ib}{n}\right)^{3}=\frac{b}{n}
                            \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{ib}{n}\right)^{3}
                     = \frac{b^4}{n^4} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(i)^3$    
    \\
    \\ $:=\frac {b^4}{n^4} \left(\frac{n^2 + 2n+1}{4}\right) 
         =\frac {b^4}{4}   \left( \frac{n^2 +2n+1}{4}\right)$
    \\
    \\
    \\ $L(f,Pn) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} mi\left(\frac{b}{n}\right) 
                = \sum_{i=1}^{n}    \left(\frac{b}{n}\right)
                                    \left(\frac{(i-1)b}{n}\right)^{3}$
    \\$=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}{i^{3}} 
       =\frac{b^{4}}{4} \left(\frac{n^{2}+2n+1}{4}\right)$
    \\Como limite superior e inferior son iguales 
        $\therefore \int_{0}^{b} x^3\,dx =\frac{b^{4}}{4} $

\item   Considera las funciones 
            $f_{1}(x)=1+x^{2}$, $f_{2}(x)=\sqrt{x}$, 
            $f_{3}(x)=x^{2}-\frac{x}{2}y$,
            $f_{4}(x) = \ln(1+x)$ para $x \epsilon \left[ 0,1 \right]$. 
Calcula las sumas superiores e inferiores utilizando particiones superiores con $n \epsilon \{10,15,25\}$.

Para la funcion ${ f }_{ 1 }\left( x \right) =1+{ x }^{2}$
    \\Con n = 10
    \\
    \\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (1+1.01+1.04+1.09+1.16+1.25+1.36+1.49+1.64+1.81)=1.285$
    \\
    \\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    paticion & ax & f(ax) \\
    \hline
    (0,1/10) & 1/10 & 1 \\
    \hline
    (1/10,2/10) & 1/10 & 1.01 \\
    \hline
    (2/10,3/10) & 1/10 & 1.04 \\
    \hline
    (3/10,4/10) & 1/10 & 1.09 \\
    \hline
    (4/10,5/10) & 1/10 & 1.16 \\
    \hline
    (5/10,6/10) & 1/10 & 1.25 \\
    \hline
    (6/10,7/10) & 1/10 & 1.36 \\
    \hline
    (7/10,8/10) & 1/10 & 1.49 \\
    \hline
    (8/10,9/10) & 1/10 & 1.64 \\
    \hline
    (9/10,1) & 1/10 & 1.81 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

$S=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (1.01+1.04+1.09+1.16+1.25+1.36+1.49+1.64+1.81+2)=1.385$
    \\
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    paticion & ax & f(ax) \\
    \hline
    (0,1/10) & 1/10 & 1.01 \\
    \hline
    (1/10,2/10) & 1/10 & 1.04 \\
    \hline
    (2/10,3/10) & 1/10 & 1.09 \\
    \hline
    (3/10,4/10) & 1/10 & 1.16 \\
    \hline
    (4/10,5/10) & 1/10 & 1.25 \\
    \hline
    (5/10,6/10) & 1/10 & 1.36 \\
    \hline
    (6/10,7/10) & 1/10 & 1.49 \\
    \hline
    (7/10,8/10) & 1/10 & 1.64 \\
    \hline
    (8/10,9/10) & 1/10 & 1.81 \\
    \hline
    (9/10,1) & 1/10 & 2 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

Con n=15

    $s=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (1+1.04+1.017+1.04+1.071+1.111+1.16+1.217+1.284+1.36+1.444+1.537+1.64+1.75+1.87)=1.300$
    \\
    \\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    particion & n & f(x) \\
    \hline
    (0,1/15) & 1/15 & 1 \\
    \hline
    (1/15,2/15) & 1/15 & 1.004 \\
    \hline
    (2/15,3/15) & 1/15 & 1.017 \\
    \hline
    (3/15,4/15) & 1/15 & 1.04 \\
    \hline
    (4/15,5/15) & 1/15 & 1.071 \\
    \hline
    (5/15,6/15) & 1/15 & 1.111 \\
    \hline
    (6/15,7/15) & 1/15 & 1.16 \\
    \hline
    (7/15,8/15) & 1/15 & 1.217 \\
    \hline
    (8/15,9/15) & 1/15 & 1.284 \\
    \hline
    (9/15,10/15) & 1/15 & 1.36 \\
    \hline
    (10/15,11/15) & 1/15 & 1.444 \\
    \hline
    (11/15,12/15) & 1/15 & 1.537 \\
    \hline
    (12/15,13/15) & 1/15 & 1.64 \\
    \hline
    (13/15,14/15) & 1/15 & 1.75 \\
    \hline
    (14/15,1) & 1/15 & 1.87 \\
    \hline

    \end{tabular}

$S=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (1.04+1.017+1.04+1.071+1.111+1.16+1.217+1.284+1.36+1.444+1.537+1.64+1.75+1.87+2)=1.367$
    \\
    \\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    particion & n & f(x) \\
    \hline
    (0,1/15) & 1/15 & 1.004 \\
    \hline
    (1/15,2/15) & 1/15 & 1.017 \\
    \hline
    (2/15,3/15) & 1/15 & 1.04 \\
    \hline
    (3/15,4/15) & 1/15 & 1.071 \\
    \hline
    (4/15,5/15) & 1/15 & 1.111 \\
    \hline
    (5/15,6/15) & 1/15 & 1.16 \\
    \hline
    (6/15,7/15) & 1/15 & 1.217 \\
    \hline
    (7/15,8/15) & 1/15 & 1.284 \\
    \hline
    (8/15,9/15) & 1/15 & 1.36 \\
    \hline
    (9/15,10/15) & 1/15 & 1.444 \\
    \hline
    (10/15,11/15) & 1/15 & 1.537 \\
    \hline
    (11/15,12/15) & 1/15 & 1.64 \\
    \hline
    (12/15,13/15) & 1/15 & 1.75 \\
    \hline
    (13/15,14/15) & 1/15 & 1.87 \\
    \hline
    (14/15,1) & 1/15 & 2 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

con n=25
    \\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (1+1.001+1.006+1.014+1.025+1.04+1.057+1.078+1.102+1.129+1.16+1.193+1.230+1.270+1.313+1.36+1.409+1.462+1.518+1.577+1.64+
    1.705+1.774+1.846+1.921=1.313$
    \\
    \\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    particion & n & f(x) \\
    \hline
    (0,1/25) & 1/25 & 1 \\
    \hline
    (1/25,2/25) & 1/25 & 1.001 \\
    \hline
    (2/25,3/25) & 1/25 & 1.006 \\
    \hline
    (3/25,4/25) & 1/25 & 1.014 \\
    \hline
    (4/25,5/25) & 1/25 & 1.025 \\
    \hline
    (5/25,6/25) & 1/25 & 1.04 \\
    \hline
    (6/25,7/25) & 1/25 & 1.057 \\
    \hline
    (7/25,8/25) & 1/25 & 1.078 \\
    \hline
    (8/25,9/25) & 1/25 & 1.102 \\
    \hline
    (9/25,10/25) & 1/25 & 1.129 \\
    \hline
    (10/25,11/25) & 1/25 & 1.16 \\
    \hline
    (11/25,12/25) & 1/25 & 1.193 \\
    \hline
    (12/25,13/25) & 1/25 & 1.230 \\
    \hline
    (13/25,14/25) & 1/25 & 1.270 \\
    \hline
    (14/25,15/25) & 1/25 & 1.313 \\
    \hline
    (15/25,16/25) & 1/25 & 1.36 \\
    \hline
    (16/25,17/25) & 1/25 & 1.409 \\
    \hline
    (17/25,18/25) & 1/25 & 1.462 \\
    \hline
    (18/25,19/25) & 1/25 & 1.518 \\
    \hline
    (19/25,20/25) & 1/25 & 1.577 \\
    \hline
    (20/25,21/25) & 1/25 & 1.64 \\
    \hline
    (21/25,22/25) & 1/25 & 1.705 \\
    \hline
    (22/25,23/25) & 1/25 & 1.774 \\
    \hline
    (23/25,24/25) & 1/25 & 1.846 \\
    \hline
    (24/25,1) & 1/25 & 1.921 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

$S=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (1.001+1.006+1.014+1.025+1.04+1.057+1.078+1.102+1.129+1.16+1.193+1.230+1.270+1.313+1.36+1.409+1.462+1.518+1.577+1.64+
    1.705+1.774+1.846+1.921+2=1.353$
    \\
    \\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    particion & n & f(x) \\
    \hline
    (0,1/25) & 1/25 & 1 \\
    \hline
    (1/25,2/25) & 1/25 & 1.001 \\
    \hline
    (2/25,3/25) & 1/25 & 1.006 \\
    \hline
    (3/25,4/25) & 1/25 & 1.014 \\
    \hline
    (4/25,5/25) & 1/25 & 1.025 \\
    \hline
    (5/25,6/25) & 1/25 & 1.04 \\
    \hline
    (6/25,7/25) & 1/25 & 1.057 \\
    \hline
    (7/25,8/25) & 1/25 & 1.078 \\
    \hline
    (8/25,9/25) & 1/25 & 1.102 \\
    \hline
    (9/25,10/25) & 1/25 & 1.129 \\
    \hline
    (10/25,11/25) & 1/25 & 1.16 \\
    \hline
    (11/25,12/25) & 1/25 & 1.193 \\
    \hline
    (12/25,13/25) & 1/25 & 1.230 \\
    \hline
    (13/25,14/25) & 1/25 & 1.270 \\
    \hline
    (14/25,15/25) & 1/25 & 1.313 \\
    \hline
    (15/25,16/25) & 1/25 & 1.36 \\
    \hline
    (16/25,17/25) & 1/25 & 1.409 \\
    \hline
    (17/25,18/25) & 1/25 & 1.462 \\
    \hline
    (18/25,19/25) & 1/25 & 1.518 \\
    \hline
    (19/25,20/25) & 1/25 & 1.577 \\
    \hline
    (20/25,21/25) & 1/25 & 1.64 \\
    \hline
    (21/25,22/25) & 1/25 & 1.705 \\
    \hline
    (22/25,23/25) & 1/25 & 1.774 \\
    \hline
    (23/25,24/25) & 1/25 & 1.846 \\
    \hline
    (24/25,1) & 1/25 & 1.921 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

Para la funcion: ${ f }_{2}\left( x \right) =\sqrt { x }$
    \\Con n=10
    \\
    \\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (0+.316+.447+.547+.632+.707+.774+.836+.894+.948)=.610$
    \\
    \\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    paticion & ax & f(ax) \\
    \hline
    (0,1/10) & 1/10 & 0 \\
    \hline
    (1/10,2/10) & 1/10 & .316 \\
    \hline
    (2/10,3/10) & 1/10 & .447 \\
    \hline
    (3/10,4/10) & 1/10 & .547 \\
    \hline
    (4/10,5/10) & 1/10 & .632 \\
    \hline
    (5/10,6/10) & 1/10 & .707 \\
    \hline
    (6/10,7/10) & 1/10 & .774 \\
    \hline
    (7/10,8/10) & 1/10 & .836 \\
    \hline
    (8/10,9/10) & 1/10 & .894 \\
    \hline
    (9/10,1) & 1/10 & .948 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \\
    \\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (.316+.447+.547+.632+.707+.774+.836+.894+.948+1)=.710$
    \\
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    paticion & ax & f(ax) \\
    \hline
    (0,1/10) & 1/10 & .316 \\
    \hline
    (1/10,2/10) & 1/10 & .447 \\
    \hline
    (2/10,3/10) & 1/10 & .547 \\
    \hline
    (3/10,4/10) & 1/10 & .632 \\
    \hline
    (4/10,5/10) & 1/10 & .707 \\
    \hline
    (5/10,6/10) & 1/10 & .774 \\
    \hline
    (6/10,7/10) & 1/10 & .836 \\
    \hline
    (7/10,8/10) & 1/10 & .894 \\
    \hline
    (8/10,9/10) & 1/10 & .948 \\
    \hline
    (9/10,1) & 1/10 & 1 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \\
    \\Con n=15
    \\
    \\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (0+.258+.365+.447+.516+.577+.632+.683+.730+.774+.816+.856+.894+.930+.966)=.629$
    \\
    \\\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    particion & n & f(x) \\
    \hline
    (0,1/15) & 1/15 & 0 \\
    \hline
    (1/15,2/15) & 1/15 & .258 \\
    \hline
    (2/15,3/15) & 1/15 & .365 \\
    \hline
    (3/15,4/15) & 1/15 & .447 \\
    \hline
    (4/15,5/15) & 1/15 & .516 \\
    \hline
    (5/15,6/15) & 1/15 & .577 \\
    \hline
    (6/15,7/15) & 1/15 & .632 \\
    \hline
    (7/15,8/15) & 1/15 & .683 \\
    \hline
    (8/15,9/15) & 1/15 & .730 \\
    \hline
    (9/15,10/15) & 1/15 & .774 \\
    \hline
    (10/15,11/15) & 1/15 & .816 \\
    \hline
    (11/15,12/15) & 1/15 & .856 \\
    \hline
    (12/15,13/15) & 1/15 & .894 \\
    \hline
    (13/15,14/15) & 1/15 & .930 \\
    \hline
    (14/15,1) & 1/15 & .966 \\
    \hline

    \end{tabular}

$S=\frac{1}{15} (.258+.365+.447+.516+.577+.632+.683+.730+.774+.816+.856+.894+.930+.966+1)=.696$
    \\
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    particion & n & f(x) \\
    \hline
    (0,1/15) & 1/15 & .258 \\
    \hline
    (1/15,2/15) & 1/15 & .365 \\
    \hline
    (2/15,3/15) & 1/15 & .447 \\
    \hline
    (3/15,4/15) & 1/15 & .516 \\
    \hline
    (4/15,5/15) & 1/15 & .577 \\
    \hline
    (5/15,6/15) & 1/15 & .632 \\
    \hline
    (6/15,7/15) & 1/15 & .683 \\
    \hline
    (7/15,8/15) & 1/15 & .730 \\
    \hline
    (8/15,9/15) & 1/15 & .774 \\
    \hline
    (9/15,10/15) & 1/15 & .816 \\
    \hline
    (10/15,11/15) & 1/15 & .856 \\
    \hline
    (11/15,12/15) & 1/15 & .894 \\
    \hline
    (12/15,13/15) & 1/15 & .930 \\
    \hline
    (13/15,14/15) & 1/15 & .966 \\
    \hline
    (14/15,1) & 1/15 & 1 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

con $n=25$

$s=\frac{1}{25}(0+.2+.282+.364+.4+.447+.489+.529+.565+.6+.632+.663+.692+
                  .721+.748+.774+.8+.824+.848+.871+.894+.916+.938+.959+.979)=.645$
    \\
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    particion & n & f(x) \\
    \hline
    (0,1/25) & 1/25 & 0 \\
    \hline
    (1/25,2/25) & 1/25 & .2 \\
    \hline
    (2/25,3/25) & 1/25 & .282 \\
    \hline
    (3/25,4/25) & 1/25 & .364 \\
    \hline
    (4/25,5/25) & 1/25 & .4 \\
    \hline
    (5/25,6/25) & 1/25 & .447 \\
    \hline
    (6/25,7/25) & 1/25 & .489 \\
    \hline
    (7/25,8/25) & 1/25 & .529 \\
    \hline
    (8/25,9/25) & 1/25 & .565 \\
    \hline
    (9/25,10/25) & 1/25 & .6 \\
    \hline
    (10/25,11/25) & 1/25 & .632 \\
    \hline
    (11/25,12/25) & 1/25 & .663 \\
    \hline
    (12/25,13/25) & 1/25 & .692 \\
    \hline
    (13/25,14/25) & 1/25 & .721 \\
    \hline
    (14/25,15/25) & 1/25 & .748 \\
    \hline
    (15/25,16/25) & 1/25 & .774 \\
    \hline
    (16/25,17/25) & 1/25 & .8 \\
    \hline
    (17/25,18/25) & 1/25 & .824 \\
    \hline
    (18/25,19/25) & 1/25 & .848 \\
    \hline
    (19/25,20/25) & 1/25 & .871 \\
    \hline
    (20/25,21/25) & 1/25 & .894 \\
    \hline
    (21/25,22/25) & 1/25 & .916 \\
    \hline
    (22/25,23/25) & 1/25 & .938 \\
    \hline
    (23/25,24/25) & 1/25 & .959 \\
    \hline
    (24/25,1) & 1/25 & .979 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

$S=\frac{1}{25} (.2+.282+.364+.4+.447+.489+.529+.565+.6+.632+.663+.692+.721+.748+.774+.8+.824+.848+.871+.894+.916+.938+.959+.979+1)=.685$
    \\
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    particion & n & f(x) \\
    \hline
    (0,1/25) & 1/25 & .2 \\
    \hline
    (1/25,2/25) & 1/25 & .282 \\
    \hline
    (2/25,3/25) & 1/25 & .364 \\
    \hline
    (3/25,4/25) & 1/25 & .4 \\
    \hline
    (4/25,5/25) & 1/25 & .447 \\
    \hline
    (5/25,6/25) & 1/25 & .489 \\
    \hline
    (6/25,7/25) & 1/25 & .529 \\
    \hline
    (7/25,8/25) & 1/25 & .565 \\
    \hline
    (8/25,9/25) & 1/25 & .6 \\
    \hline
    (9/25,10/25) & 1/25 & .632 \\
    \hline
    (10/25,11/25) & 1/25 & .663 \\
    \hline
    (11/25,12/25) & 1/25 & .692 \\
    \hline
    (12/25,13/25) & 1/25 & .721 \\
    \hline
    (13/25,14/25) & 1/25 & .748 \\
    \hline
    (14/25,15/25) & 1/25 & .774 \\
    \hline
    (15/25,16/25) & 1/25 & .8 \\
    \hline
    (16/25,17/25) & 1/25 & .824 \\
    \hline
    (17/25,18/25) & 1/25 & .848 \\
    \hline
    (18/25,19/25) & 1/25 & .871 \\
    \hline
    (19/25,20/25) & 1/25 & .894 \\
    \hline
    (20/25,21/25) & 1/25 & .916 \\
    \hline
    (21/25,22/25) & 1/25 & .938 \\
    \hline
    (22/25,23/25) & 1/25 & .959 \\
    \hline
    (23/25,24/25) & 1/25 & .979 \\
    \hline
    (24/25,1) & 1/25 & 1 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}

Para la funcion: ${ f }_{ 3 }\left( x \right) ={ x }^{2}-\frac { x }{2} $
    \\Con n=10
    \\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (0-.04-.06-.06-.04+0+.06+.14+.24+.36)=.059$
    \\
    \\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (-.04-.06-.06-.04+0+.06+.14+.24+.36+.5)=.11$
    \\
    \\Con n=15
    \\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (0-.02-.04-.06-.062-.055-.04-.015+.017+.06-.11+.17+.24+.31+.40)=.053$
    \\
    \\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (-.02-.04-.06-.062-.055-.04-.015+.017+.06-.11+.17+.24+.31+.40+.5)=.086$
    \\
    \\Con n=25
    \\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (0-.018-.033-.045-.054-.06-.062-.061-.057-.05-.04-.026-.009+.010+.033+.06+.089+.122+.158+.197+.24+.28+.33+.38+.44)=.073$
    \\
    \\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (-.018-.033-.045-.054-.06-.062-.061-.057-.05-.04-.026-.009+.010+.033+.06+.089+.122+.158+.197+.24+.28+.33+.38+.44+.5)=.093$

Para la funcion: ${ f }_{ 4 }\left( x \right) =\ln { \left( 1+x \right)  }$
    \\Con n=10
    \\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (0+.099+.18+.26+.33+.40+.47+.53+.58+.64)=.349$
    \\
    \\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 10 } (.099+.18+.26+.33+.40+.47+.53+.58+.64+.69)=.418$
    \\
    \\Con n=15
    \\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (0+.06+.12+.18+.23+.28+.33+.38+.42+.47+.51+.55+.58+.62+.65)=.359$
    \\
    \\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 15 } (.06+.12+.18+.23+.28+.33+.38+.42+.47+.51+.55+.58+.62+.65+.69)=.405$
    \\
    \\Con n=25
    \\$s=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (0+.03+.07+.11+.14+.18+.21+.24+.27+.30+.33+.36+.39+.41+.44+.47+.49+.51+.54+.56+.58+.60+.63+.65+.67)=.367$
    \\
    \\$S=\frac { 1 }{ 25 } (.03+.07+.11+.14+.18+.21+.24+.27+.30+.33+.36+.39+.41+.44+.47+.49+.51+.54+.56+.58+.60+.63+.65+.67+.69)=.395$
    \\
    \\
\item   Dibuja las regiones representadas por las siguientes integrales, y luego, calcula el area de dichas regiones utilizando geometria elemental.
    \\
    \\$\left. a \right)$ $\int _{ -3 }^{ 3 }{ 2x dx } $
    \\
    \\\includegraphics[scale=.2]{example-image}% I havent your image
    \\sabemos que el area de un triangulo es $A=\frac { b\cdot h }{2} $
    \\Se puede observar la presencia de 2 triangulos que relacionan la f(x) en la region acotada
    \\$A_{ 1 }=\frac { \left( 3-0 \right) \left( 6 \right)  }{2} =9{ u }^{2}$
    \\$A_{2}=\frac { \left( 0-3 \right) \left( 6 \right)  }{2} =-9{ u }^{2}$
    \\$A_{ T }=A_{ 1 }+A_{2}=9{ u }^{2}-9{ u }^{2}=0$

$\left. b \right)$ $\int _{ -2 }^{ 3 }{ (2x+4)dx } $
    \\
    \\$A_{ T }=\frac { \left( 3-(-2) \right) \left( 10 \right)  }{2} =25{ u }^{2}$
    \\
    \\$\left. c \right)$ $\int _{ -2 }^{ 3 }{ 4 dx } $
    \\
    \\$A=(1-(-2))(4)=12{ u }^{2}$
    \\
    \\$\left. d \right)$ $\int _{ 0 }^{ 5 }{ \sqrt { 25-{ x }^{2} } dx } $
    \\
    \\$A=\frac { \pi { r }^{2} }{ 4 } =\frac { \pi (5)^{2} }{ 4 } =\frac { 25\pi  }{ 4 } =19.63{ u }^{2}$
    \\
    \\$\left. e \right)$ $\int _{ -2 }^{ 3 }{ \left| x \right| dx } $
    \\
    \\$A_{ 1 }=\frac { \left( 3-0 \right) \left( 3 \right)  }{2} =9/2{ u }^{2}$
    \\$A_{2}=\frac { \left( 0-(-2) \right) \left( 2 \right)  }{2} =2{ u }^{2}$
    \\$A_{ T }=A_{ 1 }+A_{2}=9/2{ u }^{2}+2{ u }^{2}=06.5{ u }^{2}$
    \\$\left. f \right)$ $\int _{ -1 }^{ 1 }{ \left( 2x-\left| x \right|  \right) dx } $
    \\$A_{ 1 }=\frac { \left( (1-0) \right) \left( 1 \right)  }{2} =1/2{ u }^{2}$
    \\$A_{2}=\frac { \left( 0-(-1) \right) \left( -3 \right)  }{2} =-3/2{ u }^{2}$
    \\$A_{ T }=A_{ 1 }+A_{2}=1/2{ u }^{2}-3/2{ u }^{2}=-1{ u }^{2}$ pero por valor absoluto es positivo.
\item   Evalua las integrales para la funcion f que se muestra en la figura de abajo.
    \\$\left. a \right)$ $\int _{ 0 }^{2}{ f\left( x \right)dx }$
    \\
    \\el area del primer semicirculo sera negativa por estasdebajo del eje "x" y se debe divdir entre 2 ya que es un semicirculo
    \\
    \\$A=-\frac { \pi { r }^{2} }{2} =-\frac { \pi { \left( 1 \right)  }^{2} }{2} =-\frac { \pi  }{2} $
    \\
    \\$\left. b \right)$ $\int _{ 0 }^{ 6 }{ f\left( x \right) dx }$
    \\
    \\Sabemos:
    \\${ A_{ 1 } }=-\frac { \pi  }{2} $
    \\y
    \\${ A_{2} }=\frac { \pi { r }^{2} }{2} =\frac { \pi { \left( 2 \right)  }^{2} }{2} =\frac { 4\pi  }{2} =2\pi $
    \\Entonces el area total=
    \\$ { A_{ T } }=A_{ 1 }+A_{2}=-\frac { \pi  }{2} +2\pi =\frac { 3\pi  }{2} $
%
    \\$\left. c \right)$ $\int _{ 1 }^{ 4 }{ f\left( x \right) dx }$
\end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```